# Store private key for python wsgi application using ligthttpd server

Tags: python, wsgi

I am implementing ECDH algorighm using python wsgi application using [lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) server. What is the conventional way to store the private key from my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store it permanently, you can store it to a file

```
with open('file', 'rw') as f:
    f.write(private_key_variable)
```

if you want to keep it as an environment variable you can do it as such

```
import os

# Set environment variables
os.environ['PRIVATE_KEY'] = private_key_variable
```